# How to tell if a word is meaningless in text?

Tags: java, rss, hashmap, nlp, search-engine

I'm creating a mini search engine in Java which basically grabs all of the RSS feeds that a user specifies and then allows him or her to choose a single word to search for. Since the RSS feed documents are fairly limited in number, I'm thinking about processing the documents first before the user enters his or her search term. I want to process them by creating hashmaps linking certain keywords to a collection of records which contain the articles themselves and the number of times the word appears in the article. But, how would I determine the keywords? How can I tell which words are meaningless and which aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "what words should I ignore?" is generally named stopwords. The best search engines do not use stopwords. If I am a fan of the band "The The", I would be bummed if your search engine couldn't find them. Also, searching for exact phrases can be screwed up by a naive stopwords implementation.

By the way, the hashmap you're talking about is called an inverted index. I recommend reading this (free, online) book to get an introduction to how search engines are built: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html

Answer (score 1):

In [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), I believe these are called 'stopwords'.

I believe they just use a [text file](http://trac.foswiki.org/browser/trunk/SolrPlugin/solr/multicore/_template/conf/stopwords.txt?rev=11498) to define all the words that they will not search on.

Answer (score 1):

A small extract re. stopwords from [NLTK from Ch. 2](http://nltk.org/book/ch02.html#stopwords_index_term):

> There is also a corpus of stopwords, that is, high-frequency words
>   like the, to and also that we sometimes want to filter out of a
>   document before further processing. Stopwords usually have little
>   lexical content, and their presence in a text fails to distinguish it
>   from other texts.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stopwords.words('english')
['a', "a's", 'able', 'about', 'above', 'according', 'accordingly', 'across',
'actually', 'after', 'afterwards', 'again', 'against', "ain't", 'all', 'allow',
'allows', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', 'already', 'also', 'although', 'always', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stopwords are one thing you should use. Lots of stopword lists are available on the web.

However I'm writing an answer because the previous ones didn't mention [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tfidf) which is a metric for how important a word is in the context of your corpus of documents.

A word is more likely to be a keyword foe a document if it appears a lot in it (term frequency) and doesn't appear frequently in other documents (inverse document frequency). This way words like a, the, where, are naturally ignored, because they appear in every document.

P.S. On a related topic, you'll probably be interested in other lists, i.e. swearwords :)
P.P.S. Hashmaps are a good thing, but you should also check suffix trees for your task.